# Are there infinite involutory matrices?

Tags: matrices, involutions, infinite-matrices

This is really a 3 part question:-

> Are there infinite involutory matrices of a given order $n\times n$?

This [article](https://mathinstructor.net/2012/03/example-of-involutory-matrix/) claims that there are infinite involutory matrices, but I think it only claims that only by counting identity matrices for all possible orders.

> If yes, then does this include both real and complex matrices? or only one of these 2 types of matrix constitutes and infinite number of involutory matrices?

The [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involutory_matrix) article mentions a few matrices that are not $I_{n}$ or $(-I_{n})$ of both complex or real-only element types but does not comment on the number of possible matrices.

> If not, is it possible to calculate number of involutory matrices for the order $n\times n$?

I am a high school student so if you can give a simpler proof would be appreciated. (However please do tell even if it is not possible using elementary mathematics.)

Comment: Here's a suggestion: for $n=2$ write down the (real) matrix of a reflection in the line $y=\tan\theta x$. (Such a transformation is clearly involutory).

Comment: @ancientmathematician OK that is clear to me. I can understand the argument for $3\times 3$ matrix too, does this generalize to the nth dimension? Also what about complex involutory matrices? are they a finite set or infinite?

Comment: If there are infinitely many real ones then there are infinitely many complex ones: every real matrix is also a complex matrix. For dimension $n$ why not just put a 2x2 one in the top left and then 1s on the diagonal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually, consider the linear transformations defined by rotating the space through an angle $\theta$, flipping one of the coordinate axes, and rotating back. This is clearly an involution, and since it is a linear transformation, there is a matrix representing it. They are also all distinct, because for each $\theta$, there is a different unit vector that gets flipped around exactly (it's the one that gets rotated to the flipped axis in the first step). Since there are infinitely many angles $\theta$, there are infinitely many such transforms.

For a more general version of this argument, let $D$ be a diagonal matrix whose nonzero elements are all $\pm 1$ that is not $I$ or $-I$ and let $O$ be an orthogonal matrix. Then
$$
T = O^TDO
$$
is an involution, and this involution will in general be distinct for distinct $O$.